# Outlook emailObj.Body not sending the whole email on certain emails

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using a VBA script to send the email body to another script. Some emails it send the whole email body. However on some emails it stops.

I can't see any pattern to when it will and wont send the whole body. The code I am using to send the data is:

```
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
Case "Explorer"
    Set emailObj = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
 Case "Inspector"
    Set emailObj = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Select
CurrItem = emailObj.Body
URLs = ShellRun("python useEmailData.py """ & CurrItem & """")
```

This does work, however sometimes CurrItem is not the full email body, other times it is the whole email.

Comment: You have to send an email from a script to a script?  Why?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Also, [tag:vbscript] and [tag:vba] are not the same thing, and you appear to be using a [tag:python] file but haven't mentioned or shared it.  Please correct your tags.  When "looking for a pattern", how did the result vary when it was an `Explorer` object vs. an `Inspector` object?  I'm not sure why you're not using the `MailItem` object. Have you studied how the [Outlook Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/object-model-outlook-vba-reference) works?

Comment: Please see "[mcve]" as well as the [tour] and "[ask]".  There's more information at [help/on-topic] and also [here is a checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) that may be helpful when you [edit] your question to provide more information including clearly demonstrating what you **have**, what you're **trying** to do, and at least a few examples of **what you're tried so far**.

Comment: I am trying to send the contents of the currently selected email to a python script. As I said the code works however some emails are truncated in passing to python, it isn't the python script doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the command line is limited. Plus it can be truncated if special characters are present (e.g. a quote) . You must encode the string properly.

Comment: The email body isn't too long as longer messages are sent so it must be special characters. How could I pass the object ignoring the special characters?